# Calc a value on its decimal version

Tags: bash, math, floating-point, decimal, arithmetic-expressions

1 gwei = 0.000000001 ether

There's a program that displays only `156489673002` (156 gwei), which is `0.000000156489673002` ether.

But how to, in Bash, calculate how many ether is `156489673002` (so the output is `0.000000156489673002`)?

Comment: You use, instead of bash, a language which can do fractional arithmetic: `bc`, `awk` and `zsh` for instance, though if you need high precision, `bc` is probably the best choice. Other good alternatives are i.e. Ruby, Perl, Python and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result with `awk`:

```
echo "0.1 0.1" | awk '{printf "%.18f\n", 156489673002 / 1000000000000000000}'
```

or

```
echo "0.1 0.1" | awk '{printf "%.18f\n", 156489673002 / 1e18}'
```

Comment: Wrong.  As 156489673002, formated, is 0.000000156489673002 ether, it can't be 156.489673002 ether.

Comment: My question is about how to format `156489673002` so it is `0.000000156489673002`.

Comment: `156489673002` = 156 gwei.

Comment: I ask how to format so the output will be `0.000000156489673002`; and not `156.489673002`.

Comment: I don't get you, if you enter `156489673002` in the gwei field of the [online converter](https://eth-converter.com/), you get `156.489673002` ether,  not `0.000000156489673002`

Comment: That's not the conversion I meant in the question. Its about how to format `156489673002` as `0.000000156489673002`.

Comment: So you mean wei instead of gwei?

Comment: I still mean gwei. `0.000000001` ether is 1 `gwei`.

Comment: I just ask how to format the input `156489673002` to the output `0.000000156489673002`

Comment: Obviously you need to add more zeros to the dividend, `echo "0.1 0.1" | awk '{printf "%.18f\n", 156489673002 / 1000000000000000000}'` gives you `0.000000156489673002`

Comment: Now it works, even for numbers smaller than `156489673002` (such as ` 75675526908`). Thank you. Please update your answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I updated it some minutes ago ;)